# How to make this table nicer

Tags: tables

My current table is not so nice. The space is too tight. How to make this table nicer?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\newcommand\tbc{{\textstyle\bigcup}} % handy shortcut macro
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Semantic models of the OCCR model}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|m{2.5cm}<{\centering}|m{1.6cm}<{\centering}|m{8cm}<{\centering}|}
\hline
\textbf{Models}& \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description}  
\\
\hline 
Reconfiguration& AS & Asset information in the manufacturing domain, such as hardware (equipment and tooling), software, the human workforce, and enabling technologies for achieving reconfiguration. 

\\ 
\hline Capacity model& CM &   A structured representation of manufacturing KPIs that monitor the performance state on the shop floor focusing on the reconfiguration. 
\\ 
\hline

\end{tabular}
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You ask how to make the table nicer. So

1. remove all vertical rules that have no usefulness;
2. use top alignment, there's no need for vertically center the entries;
3. replace rules in the middle with vertical space;
4. use `tabularx` in order to fill the text width and don't worry about computing widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Semantic models of the OCCR model}
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}

%\scriptsize

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l c X @{}}
\toprule
Models & Symbol & Description \\
\midrule
Assets & AS &
  Asset information in the manufacturing domain, such as hardware
  (equipment and tooling), software, the human workforce, and enabling
  technologies for achieving reconfiguration. 
\\
\addlinespace
Capacity model & CM &
  A structured representation of manufacturing KPIs that monitor the
  performance state on the shop floor focusing on the reconfiguration. 
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Why `caption`? Because it makes top captions well separated from the table (the standard classes are set up for *bottom* captions).

The `\label` is better placed next to the relevant `\caption`.

[image]

You can have vertical centering, but I don't recommend it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Semantic models of the OCCR model}
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}

%\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}{m}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l c X @{}}
\toprule
Models & Symbol & Description \\
\midrule
Assets & AS &
  Asset information in the manufacturing domain, such as hardware
  (equipment and tooling), software, the human workforce, and enabling
  technologies for achieving reconfiguration. 
\\
\addlinespace
Capacity model & CM &
  A structured representation of manufacturing KPIs that monitor the
  performance state on the shop floor focusing on the reconfiguration. 
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, your `\tbc` command should be

```
\newcommand{\tbc}{\mathop{\textstyle\bigcup}}
```

or the symbol wouldn't have the properties of a math operator as regards to spacing.

Comment: How to put the text in all columns in the middle? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @James Do you need it? It would make the table *less* readable. See the comparison.

Comment: Yes, I think I need it cause I have a multi-column in my case. I need to use multi rows in symbols. So I need to put the content in model in the middle

Answer (score 7):

You are loosing a lot of space for your first two columns. If you make them smaller, you have more room for the long description and you can even use a bigger font, which will be nicer to read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\newcommand\tbc{{\textstyle\bigcup}} % handy shortcut macro
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Semantic models of the OCCR model}
\small
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|Q[c,1.4cm]|c|X[c]|},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  cells={valign=m}
}
\hline
Models& Symbol & Description\\
\hline 
Re\-con\-fig\-uration& AS & Asset information in the manufacturing domain, such as hardware (equipment and tooling), software, the human workforce, and enabling technologies for achieving reconfiguration.\\ 
\hline Capacity model& CM &   A structured representation of manufacturing KPIs that monitor the performance state on the shop floor focusing on the reconfiguration.\\ 
\hline
\end{tblr}
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have slightly changed my original table. Could you please have a look at my updated question? Thanks.

Comment: @James Updated..

Answer (score 5):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Semantic models of the OCCR model}
\label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec    = {Q[c,m]Q[c,m]X[l,m]},
hlines,vlines,
rows       = {font=\small},
row{1}     = {font=\bfseries},
cell{1}{Z} = {}{halign=c}
}
Models          & Symbol & Description                                                                                                                                                                      \\
Reconfiguration & AS     & Asset information in the manufacturing domain, such as hardware (equipment and tooling), software, the human workforce, and enabling technologies for achieving reconfiguration. \\
Capacity model  & CM     & A structured representation of manufacturing KPIs that monitor the performance state on the shop floor focusing on the reconfiguration.                                          \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have slightly changed my original table. Could you please have a look at my updated question? Thanks.

Comment: @James I have updated. But your modification does not change the format of the table. You can replace the modified words directly.